# Playonlinux - Steam games won't launch

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux

I'm running Ubuntu gnome 14.04.

I installed Steam through *Playonlinux* and everything went fine.

I installed some windows games through Steam.

When I click 'play' to launch the game, I get a window saying **Preparing to launch (insert game name)** for a second or 2, then the window closes and nothing happens.

I've seen many threads about this issue out there, but none had a solution that worked for me, and many of these threads are dead.

One of the things I tried was adding `gameoverlayrenderer.dll` in Wine libraries and set it to disable. It didn't work.

**EDIT:** following Ducky's suggestions, here are the Playonlinux logs (accessible through Debug mode)

*Launching Steam:*

```
urns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33d6d8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33d6d8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33d870,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x33d870,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x10118, filter=0xe1fe92c,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x20118, filter=0xe1fe92c,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x100a3de0, 0x12035da0, {3dada31d-19ef-4dc1-b345-037927193422}, 1, 0x11faf518, (null), (null), 0x12035db8): stub
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (3): stub
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x100a3de0, 0x12035da0, {3dada31d-19ef-4dc1-b345-037927193422}, 1, 0x11faf518, (null), (null), 0x12035db8): stub
fixme:gdi:GdiInitializeLanguagePack stub
[0821/165518:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x1f5e9f8 (nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7648, 0x100d7640
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7680, 0x100d7678
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7610, 0x100d7608
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x10056360, 0x100d76b8, 0x100d76b0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x10056360, 0x100d76f0, 0x100d76e8
fixme:imm:ImmGetOpenStatus (0x135a48): semi-stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f15c (nil)): stub
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" not implemented
fixme:mscoree:CLRMetaHost_GetRuntime Unrecognized version L"v4.0"
The entry point method could not be loaded
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext ((nil), (nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7648, 0x100d7640
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7680, 0x100d7678
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7610, 0x100d7608
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x10056360, 0x100d76b8, 0x100d76b0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x10056360, 0x100d76f0, 0x100d76e8
fixme:imm:ImmGetOpenStatus (0x135a48): semi-stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f15c (nil)): stub
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" not implemented
fixme:mscoree:CLRMetaHost_GetRuntime Unrecognized version L"v4.0"
The entry point method could not be loaded
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext ((nil), (nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:system:SystemParametersInfoW Unknown action: 116
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7648, 0x100d7640
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7680, 0x100d7678
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7610, 0x100d7608
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x10056360, 0x100d76b8, 0x100d76b0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x10056360, 0x100d76f0, 0x100d76e8
fixme:imm:ImmGetOpenStatus (0x135a48): semi-stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f15c (nil)): stub
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" not implemented
fixme:mscoree:CLRMetaHost_GetRuntime Unrecognized version L"v4.0"
The entry point method could not be loaded
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext ((nil), (nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7648, 0x100d7640
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7680, 0x100d7678
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x10056360, 0x100d7610, 0x100d7608
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x10056360, 0x100d76b8, 0x100d76b0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x10056360, 0x100d76f0, 0x100d76e8
fixme:imm:ImmGetOpenStatus (0x135a48): semi-stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f15c (nil)): stub
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" not implemented
fixme:mscoree:CLRMetaHost_GetRuntime Unrecognized version L"v4.0"
The entry point method could not be loaded
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext ((nil), (nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB!
fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafecafe), STUB!
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafecafe), STUB!
IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process pipe.IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process pipe.fixme:iphlpapi:CancelIPChangeNotify (overlapped 0x9e103d0): fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB!
fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB!
fixme:iphlpapi:CancelIPChangeNotify (overlapped 0xb25f28): stub
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids 0: stub
Forced create of Win32Mutex but it already existed
Forced create of Win32Event but it already existed
Forced create of Win32Event but it already existed
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
[2014-08-21 16:55:11] Startup - updater built Aug 13 2014 14:18:40
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2014-08-21 16:55:11] Checking for update on startup
[2014-08-21 16:55:11] Checking for available updates...
[2014-08-21 16:55:12] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_win32 version 1407966480, installed version 1407966480
[2014-08-21 16:55:12] Nothing to do
[2014-08-21 16:55:12] Verifying installation...
[2014-08-21 16:55:12] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2014-08-21 16:55:12] Verification complete
[2014-08-21 16:57:50] Shutdown
[08/21/14 16:59:48] - Running wine-1.7.22 Steam.exe (Working directory : /home/nils/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam_wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
[0821/165951:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(174)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
[0821/165951:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(103)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
[0821/165957:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
The entry point method could not be loaded
IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process pipe.IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process pipe.Forced create of Win32Mutex but it already existed
Forced create of Win32Event but it already existed
Forced create of Win32Event but it already existed
[2014-08-21 16:59:49] Startup - updater built Aug 13 2014 14:18:40
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2014-08-21 16:59:49] Checking for update on startup
[2014-08-21 16:59:49] Checking for available updates...
[2014-08-21 16:59:50] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_win32 version 1407966480, installed version 1407966480
[2014-08-21 16:59:50] Nothing to do
[2014-08-21 16:59:50] Verifying installation...
[2014-08-21 16:59:50] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2014-08-21 16:59:50] Verification complete
[2014-08-21 17:00:12] Shutdown
[08/21/14 17:00:22] - Running wine-1.7.22 winecfg (Working directory : /usr/share/playonlinux/python)
[08/21/14 17:00:58] - Running wine-1.7.22 Steam.exe (Working directory : /home/nils/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam_wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
[0821/170100:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(174)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
[0821/170100:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(103)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
[0821/170106:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
The entry point method could not be loaded
IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process pipe.IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process pipe.Forced create of Win32Mutex but it already existed
Forced create of Win32Event but it already existed
Forced create of Win32Event but it already existed
[2014-08-21 17:00:59] Startup - updater built Aug 13 2014 14:18:40
[2014-08-21 17:00:59] Verifying installation...
[2014-08-21 17:01:00] Verification complete
[2014-08-21 17:01:20] Shutdown
[08/21/14 17:01:30] - Running wine-1.7.22 Steam.exe (Working directory : /home/nils/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam_wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33e490 (nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fce8, 0x3f03fce0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fd20, 0x3f03fd18
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fcb0, 0x3f03fca8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fd58, 0x3f03fd50
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fd90, 0x3f03fd88
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fce8, 0x3f03fce0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fd20, 0x3f03fd18
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fcb0, 0x3f03fca8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fd58, 0x3f03fd50
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x3f006c60, 0x3f03fd90, 0x3f03fd88
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000100, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:imm:ImmGetOpenStatus (0x1f9c70): semi-stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33e368 (nil)): stub
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (3): stub
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:imm:ImmDisableTextFrameService Stub
fixme:thread:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 56, 0x33f77c, (nil) 0x33f780
fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (0x33f668 0x00000ff0 0x33f6a4) Stub!
[0821/170132:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(174)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x33f7b0, overlapped 0xb25f28): stub
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x1009a, filter=0x33f7bc,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x1009a, filter=0x33f7bc,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
[0821/170132:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(103)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f08c,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x270dff4 (nil)): stub
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x31e5d0 (nil)): stub
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_apps_get__NewEnum 0x338cd60, 0x7ffe0d4
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_ProcessImageFileName 0x338d3d0, L"C:\\Program Files\\Steam\\steam.exe"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_Name 0x338d3d0, L"Steam"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_Enabled 0x338d3d0, -1
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_apps_Add 0x338d3b8, 0x338d3d0
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {e2b3c97f-6ae1-41ac-817a-f6f92166d7dd} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {e2b3c97f-6ae1-41ac-817a-f6f92166d7dd} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x15103cc, overlapped 0x15103d0): stub
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationA (hwnd=0x100a6, filter=0x8bee4ec,flags=0x00000004) returns a fake device notification handle!
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {77f10cf0-3db5-4966-b520-b7c54fd35ed6} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {77f10cf0-3db5-4966-b520-b7c54fd35ed6} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:wbemprox:wbem_locator_ConnectServer unsupported flags
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0x7c6d1270, 0x35630b8, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0x7c6d1270
fixme:wbemprox:wbem_locator_ConnectServer unsupported flags
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0x7c6d1270, 0x35630d0, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0x7c6d1270
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl The DISK_PARTITION_INFO and DISK_DETECTION_INFO structures will not be filled
fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl The DISK_PARTITION_INFO and DISK_DETECTION_INFO structures will not be filled
fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported
fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported
fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported
fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0x100a8, 0x34d7540): stub
fixme:winhttp:get_system_proxy_autoconfig_url no support on this platform
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl discovery via DHCP not supported
fixme:winhttp:get_system_proxy_autoconfig_url no support on this platform
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationA (hwnd=0x100c0, filter=0x33e1f4,flags=0x00000004) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33d6d8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33d6d8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33d870,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x33d870,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x10118, filter=0x9bfe92c,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:win:UnregisterDeviceNotification (handle=0xcafeaffe), STUB!
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationW (hwnd=0x20118, filter=0x9bfe92c,flags=0x00000000) returns a fake device notification handle!
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x100a3de0, 0x12035da0, {3dada31d-19ef-4dc1-b345-037927193422}, 1, 0x11faf518, (null), (null), 0x12035db8): stub
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (3): stub
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x100a3de0, 0x12035da0, {3dada31d-19ef-4dc1-b345-037927193422}, 1, 0x11faf518, (null), (null), 0x12035db8): stub
fixme:gdi:GdiInitializeLanguagePack stub
[0821/170138:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x1f5e9f8 (nil)): stub
fixme:winhttp:get_system_proxy_autoconfig_url no support on this platform
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
```

*When I click on 'Play' on some game:*

```
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" not implemented
fixme:mscoree:CLRMetaHost_GetRuntime Unrecognized version L"v4.0"
The entry point method could not be loaded
fixme:system:SystemParametersInfoW Unknown action: 116
fixme:winhttp:get_system_proxy_autoconfig_url no support on this platform
fixme:winhttp:get_system_proxy_autoconfig_url no support on this platform
fixme:winhttp:get_system_proxy_autoconfig_url no support on this platform
```

Answer (score 2):

Wine -- even with help of PlayOnLinux -- really doesn't work well with 3D stuff. Also, you didn't really post that much info: it could be missing libraries, a bad graphics card (Wine really does not like integrated Intel cards, for example), an issue with sound, etc.

You could try launching Steam Wine from the terminal, and see if it outputs anything. Like this:

```
wine "~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/steam.exe"
```

Although, in your case, you'll need to use the path PlayOnLinux decides to use, since I recall it uses separate profiles for different installs (have a look around in `~/.playonlinux/`).

The WineHQ AppDB is also a really good source of information regarding specific programs: https://appdb.winehq.org/.

Also, **Steam is already on Linux** and there is already a ton of games available that have been ported over (or have been written native to Linux).

**EDIT:**

Don't expect it to work. Ever.

The issue here is missing .NET 4.0 support in WINE which a lot of games are built on (most likely in C#). Native .NET has never been one of Wine's strong points; it only managed to partially work a few years. Mono is here, however, it doesn't work to well with already-compiled code.

The other issue there is `fixme:winhttp:get_system_proxy_autoconfig_url no support on this platform`, which has had some luck at being solved by some people (e.g.: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=22732 -- solved by installing `winbind:i386` from the Ubuntu repo's, and updating the proprietry non-free nVidia drivers the OP had).

However, I'd really suggest looking at the AppDB previously mentioned above. Have a look for the game you're trying to run, and there may just be some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I added to the question the Playonlinux logs. Also I do use Steam for linux, I just wanted to try windows games, as some people reported launching many games successfully through Wine.

Comment: @SpidrJeru I updated my answer.

Comment: Actually, `dotnet40` works pretty well on Wine, when installed with `WINEPREFIX="/path/to/prefix/" winetricks dotnet40`.